# What resources must I provide to law enforcement for an adult media site? What others should I provide?

Tags: legal, adult-content

The voreaphile community (by and large) has seen better days and I'm working on a new site for them. This would qualify as a fetish community - in other words, an adult site. As is likely immediately obvious, there are no minors welcomed on such a site, and it is hosted in the USA, in West Virginia.

Two questions:

- What resources must I provide law enforcement or have available to provide them?
- What resources should I provide law enforcement beyond my immediate liability as a webmaster?

Assume (good-faith) user privacy is paramount and I don't want cops just snooping around a server. Assume, likewise, that I don't want them to confiscate the server and search the files. Considering the vulnerability introduced to people's reputations with any involvement in an adult site, I'd rather not open a chance to simply find things to declare "problematic" and investigate.

Ideally, they'd have a specific user in mind by username, ask for specific data, and I'd have that ready to hand to them fairly quickly after the request. In the real world, technology based warrants seem to be very badly limited to the specific search space.

Firmly resisting insofar as protecting innocent users - even when associated with ones who have done something illegal on my site - would be preferable. Cooperation beyond that point is quite fine to rights with me. I have no vested interest in protecting people that I can look at logs myself and see have done something criminal.

Comment: Way too many questions here. Additionally, you should be speaking to an attorney, not some Q&A website where anybody can write anything.

Comment: The first two are the only two I am concerned with here (the others are just ones I have), and I find it hard to believe that general liability and law enforcement resources aren't handled by webmasters.

Comment: The extra questions have been cut aside; I'll decide what to do with them later on. I find it hard to believe the remaining two questions are overly broad, and google hasn't been helpful.

Comment: You will have to bear in mind laws like this [SESTA](https://stopsesta.org/)

Comment: jrtapsell I don't have rights to give a point but thanks for at least something towards a right direction.

Comment: @JohnConde Remove hold or advise as to remaining issues, please?

Comment: @JohnConde your lack of advisory upon request is disheartening. (RE: status moved from hold to closed without response to my preceding comment.)